# Android MediaProjection. Почему ImageReader.acquireLatestImage ВСЕГДА возвращает Null?

Tags: java, android, screenshots

Пишу простой пример для создания Скриншотов в программе используя для этого *Android MediaProjection + ImageReader* для получения изображения. Для написания примера я использовал [этот пример](https://www.codota.com/web/assistant/code/rs/5c7c8eb62ef5570001dd7bd6#L76).

В приложении есть только одна кнопка **Capture** при нажатии на которую должнен отобразиться запрос разрешения на доступ к экрану и, собственно, после подтверждения действия, необходимо получить **Скриншот** экрана.
Но в данном случае, в логах ВСЕГДА получаю `"image: NULL"`, т.е. `ImageReader.acquireLatestImage` ВСЕГДА возвращает `NULL`.

Возможно это из-за формата, который выставляется в `ImageReader.newInstance`? По-умолчанию (как в примере) формат изображения был `0x1`, но я его заменил на `ImageFormat.RGB_565`, потому-что студия выбивала предупреждение:

> Must be one of: ImageFormat.UNKNOWN, ImageFormat.RGB_565,
> ImageFormat.YV12, ImageFormat.Y8, ImageFormat.NV16, ImageFormat.NV21,
> ImageFormat.YUY2, ImageFormat.JPEG, ImageFormat.DEPTH_JPEG,
> ImageFormat.YUV_420_888, ImageFormat.YUV_422_888,
> ImageFormat.YUV_444_888, ImageFormat.FLEX_RGB_888,
> ImageFormat.FLEX_RGBA_8888, ImageFormat.RAW_SENSOR,
> ImageFormat.RAW_PRIVATE, ImageFormat.RAW10, ImageFormat.RAW12,
> ImageFormat.DEPTH16, ImageFormat.DEPTH_POINT_CLOUD,
> ImageFormat.PRIVATE, ImageFormat.HEIC

И, собственно, мой **вопрос** - почему `ImageReader.acquireLatestImage` всегда возвращает `NUll` и как это можно пофиксить? Буду благодарен за решение иили любые идеи, которые могут привести к решению.

Готовый код:

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.ImageFormat;
import android.hardware.display.DisplayManager;
import android.hardware.display.VirtualDisplay;
import android.media.Image;
import android.media.ImageReader;
import android.media.projection.MediaProjection;
import android.media.projection.MediaProjectionManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.util.DisplayMetrics;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
    private static final String TAG = "test_t";

    private ImageReader mImageReader;
    private MediaProjectionManager mMediaProjectionManager;
    private Intent mCreateScreenCaptureIntent;
    private MediaProjection mMediaProjection;
    private VirtualDisplay mVirtualDisplay;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        View mBtnCapture = findViewById(R.id.btn_capture);
        mBtnCapture.setOnClickListener(this);

        init();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        tearDownMediaProjection();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        mMediaProjection = mMediaProjectionManager.getMediaProjection(resultCode, data);
        if (mMediaProjection != null) {
            startScreenCapture();
            takeCapture();
            stopScreenCapture();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        startActivityForResult(mCreateScreenCaptureIntent, 777);
    }

    private void init() {
        DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
        mImageReader = ImageReader.newInstance(displayMetrics.widthPixels, displayMetrics.heightPixels, ImageFormat.RGB_565, 2); // format 0x1

        mMediaProjectionManager = (MediaProjectionManager) getSystemService(MEDIA_PROJECTION_SERVICE);
        mCreateScreenCaptureIntent = mMediaProjectionManager.createScreenCaptureIntent();
    }

    private void startScreenCapture() {
        if (mMediaProjection == null)
            return;

        DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
        mVirtualDisplay = mMediaProjection.createVirtualDisplay(
                "ScreenCapture",
                displayMetrics.widthPixels,
                displayMetrics.heightPixels,
                displayMetrics.densityDpi,
                DisplayManager.VIRTUAL_DISPLAY_FLAG_AUTO_MIRROR,
                mImageReader.getSurface(), null, null);
    }

    private void stopScreenCapture() {
        if (mVirtualDisplay == null) {
            return;
        }
        mVirtualDisplay.release();
        mVirtualDisplay = null;
    }

    private void takeCapture() {
        Image image = mImageReader.acquireLatestImage();
        if (image == null) {
            Log.d(TAG, "image: NULL");
            return;
        }

        int width = image.getWidth();
        int height = image.getHeight();
        final Image.Plane[] planes = image.getPlanes();
        final ByteBuffer buffer = planes[0].getBuffer();
        int pixelStride = planes[0].getPixelStride();
        int rowStride = planes[0].getRowStride();
        int rowPadding = rowStride - pixelStride * width;
        Bitmap mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width + rowPadding / pixelStride, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        mBitmap.copyPixelsFromBuffer(buffer);
        mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(mBitmap, 0, 0, width, height);
        image.close();
        saveBitmapToFile(mBitmap);
    }

    private void saveBitmapToFile(Bitmap bitmap) {
        File directory = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "SCREEN_TEMP");
        if (!directory.exists())
            directory.mkdirs();
        String name = "shot" + new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmsss").format(new Date()) + "." + Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG.toString();
        File file = new File(directory, name);
        try {
            if (!file.exists()) {
                file.createNewFile();
            }
            FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, out);
            out.flush();
            out.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void tearDownMediaProjection() {
        if (mMediaProjection != null) {
            mMediaProjection.stop();
            mMediaProjection = null;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Скорее всего потому, что там действительно нет изображения. То есть код запроса вызывается раньше, чем MediaProjection что-то запишет в ImageReader. Поэтому рекомендую делать вызов функции takeCapture() в callback-функции OnImageAvailableListener.

Например, после инициализации imageReader зарегистрировать listener следующим образом:

```
imageReader.setOnImageAvailableListener(this, this.handler);
```

Сделать в MainActivity поддержку интерфейса Listener'a:

```
MainActivity implements ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener
```

Добавить Handler и поток исполнения как поля MainActivity:

```
final private HandlerThread handlerThread = new HandlerThread(getClass().getSimpleName(), android.os.Process.THREAD_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND);
private Handler handler;
```

В методе init() запустить поток обработки изображений и проинициализировать handler:

```
handlerThread.start()
handler = new Handler(handlerThread.getLooper());
```

Далее добавить в Ваше MainActivity:

```
@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
@Override
public void onImageAvailable(ImageReader reader)
{
     takeCapture();
}
```

Comment: Да, спасибо. Как раз тоже это заметил. Просто странно что в примере тоже не было этого слушателя